# Mostrar botón después del éxito de la función ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando mostrar un botón oculto en la función de `AJAX` al momento de que esta sea satisfactoria:

Pero no muestra el botón, agradezco su ayuda.

Código HTML:

```
<input id="btnPrueba"   type="submit"value="enviar "style="display:none;"  >
```

Código AJAX:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $().ajaxStart(function() {
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#result').hide();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#result').fadeIn('slow');
    });
   // Interceptamos el evento submit
    $('#form, #fat, #formprueba').submit(function() {
  // Enviamos el formulario usando AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            // Mostramos un mensaje con la respuesta de PHP
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);  
                $("#btnPrueba").show();

            }
        })        
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Estas juntando `javascript` con `jQuery`. Para hacerlo directamente con `jQuery` seria `$("#btnPrueba").show();` También veo que usas `getElementsById`, los `id` son únicos por lo que esa función no existe, sería `getElementById`. y para mostrarlo `document.getElementById("btnPrueba").style.display = "block";`

Comment: Para modificar la pregunta en los enlaces inferiores de la pregunta tienes uno de [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/324716/edit). El apartado de respuestas es solo para respuestas. Si tienes algo que modificar edita la pregunta y si necesitas pedir aclaraciones usa los comentarios.

Comment: Por favor, si sos el mismo usuario que tenes dos cuentas, deja un mensaje al equipo de moderacion y podemos unirte las cuentas, asi tambien podes utilizar el sitio como corresponde. Por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Comment: La respuesta que has marcado como aceptada no tiene sentido, las comillas no pueden ser el problema. como tienes el código en la pregunta debería de funcionar. Si no es así especifica mas el problema y si la respuesta a tu problema era otra solución puedes crear una respuesta detallándola.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

si podes poner el código html también sería de gran utilidad. Te recomiendo leer la documentación de jquery en el método "show" de Ajax.

Por otra parte lo que veo es que tienes doble comillas en

```
$("btnPrueba").show()
```

Prueba cambiarlo por:

```
$('#btnPrueba').show()
```

Y comentame que tal.

Comment: Hola cambie las comillas pero sigue sin aparecer el boton es raro por que los datos si los envia sin problemas arriba agregue el input del html, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo ?

Comment: Hola si lo que me mencionabas funciona a la perfeccion, pero a mi no me funcion por que estoy enviando peticiones a otro servidor y el navegador las bloquea por CORS tarde en darme cuenta pero ese era el error, gacias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Claro, no me di cuenta de comentarte eso, pero lo dice en la documentación de ajax. Un saludo !

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente tienes estos dos errores.

1. Es `document.getElementById` en singular, porque los ids son únicos en teoría.
2. El método `document.getElementById` te devuelve un elemento, y los elementos no tienen el método `show`

La solución seria cambiar esto

```
document.getElementsById("btnPrueba").show();
```

por esto:

```
$("#btnPrueba").show();
```